# Как связать таблицы по id в запросе?

Tags: android, orm

Есть 2 таблички: `albums(id, name, author, ...)` и `records(id, name, album_id, last_use, ...)`

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT albums.id
FROM albums INNER JOIN records ON albums.id = records.album_id
WHERE records.last_use > 100
ORDER BY albums.autor ASC;
```

Как воплотить его с использованием ORMLite?
С запросами внутри одно таблицы все ок, а вот с двумя и более...
Как сделать сам join я нашел: `albumsQueryBuilder.join(recordQueryBuilder)`, а вот как связать таблицы по id и сконструировать остальную часть запроса?

Comment: Читаем документайию [раз][1]. Читаем документацию [два][2].


  [1]: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Foreign-Collection
  [2]: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html

Comment: А я че-то не догнал: `inner join` это разве не связываение по `id`?